# downloaded SciPy for python, not able to use it

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I am trying to download and use SciPy. According to pip I have already downloaded it however when I try to use it python says there is no module named SciPy. I have tried using python as well as python3. Here is a copy of my console:

```
➜  ~ pip3 install SciPy
Requirement already satisfied: SciPy in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (0.19.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.8.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from SciPy) (1.14.3)
➜  ~ pip install SciPy
Requirement already satisfied: SciPy in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (0.19.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.8.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from SciPy) (1.14.3)
➜  ~ python
Python 2.7.15 (default, Jun  2 2018, 12:02:49)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import SciPy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named SciPy
>>> exit()
➜  ~ python3
Python 3.6.5 (default, Apr 28 2018, 01:16:46)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import SciPy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'SciPy'
>>> exit()
➜  ~
```

Comment: what do you mean? can you be more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imports are case-sensitive. Use

```
import scipy
```

Comment: thanks, that seems to work. If imports are case sensitive then why does `import SciPy` work?

Comment: The name of the pip package doesn't always match the name of the Python module. Here, the SciPy package contains the scipy module, so you `pip install SciPy` but `import scipy`.